# Using where clause within a partition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have huge pageview level table, where each session has multiple pageviews.

Session -> Pageviews - 1 : M

From the pageviews table, I need to consolidate the data into one row per session with meta data like FirstPageview, LastPageview, #ofvisitstoLogin

1. Firstpageview is defined as the very first pageview for a session
   (this can be login)
2. Lastpageview is defined as a pageview that is
   not /login (this cannot be login, if it is pick the pageview before
   this)
3. #ofvisitstologin is defined as the #oftimesthesession landed on login

| visitorid | sessionid | timestamp | webpagepath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 2021-01-01 10:30:00 | homepage |
| abc | 123 | 2021-01-01 10:30:50 | login |
| abc | 123 | 2021-01-01 10:31:00 | page2 |
| abc | 123 | 2021-01-01 10:32:50 | page3 |
| abc | 123 | 2021-01-01 10:33:00 | page2 |
| abc | 123 | 2021-01-01 10:35:50 | login |

The output that I want,

| visitorid | sessionid | FristPageview | LastPageview | #ofvisitstoLogin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | homepage | page2 | 2 |

Is it possible to do this with window functions? Without using subqueries / joins because this is a huge table and it affects performance.

Sample query that I have,

```
select 
     visitor_id, 
     session_id,
     first_value(webpage_path) over (partition by visitor_id, session_id order by timestamp asc) as first_pageview,
      last_value(webpage_path) over (partition by visitor_id, session_id order by timestamp asc) as last_page_view,
      sum(iff(webpage_path = 'login', 1, 0)) over (partition by visitor_id, session_id timestamp asc) as noofvisitstologin
 from pageviews;
```

But this code doesn't work because for the last_page_view column will be "login" if i run this code. But i need it to be "page2" instead.

Is this achievable without using subqueries / self join?

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using (and Redshift is not the same as Postgres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LAST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value.html) supports `IGNORE NULLS` clause and it could be combined with `NULLIF(webpage_path, 'login')`:

```
select 
 visitor_id, 
 session_id,
 first_value(webpage_path) 
 over (partition by visitor_id, session_id order by timestamp asc) as first_pageview,
 last_value(NULLIF(webpage_path,'login')) ignore nulls 
 over (partition by visitor_id, session_id order by timestamp asc) as last_page_view,
 count_if(webpage_path = 'login') 
 over (partition by visitor_id, session_id timestamp asc) as noofvisitstologin
from pageviews;
```

Second: `SUM(IIF(...))` could be replaced with [COUNT_IF()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html).